# How to translate/interpret lens patent's aspherical equation into more common form

Tags: optics

I am trying to define a lens inside of optical software from a patent. The spherical elements are no problem, but the aspherical element defined in the patent seems to follow a form I'm unfamiliar with.

The optical software expects an aspherical equation in the form of a series of coefficients, and accepts:

- Standard form
- Normalized form (normalized by base sphere)
- Zernike form

No matter what form I choose, the coefficients supplied in the patent result in an obviously ill-defined element. I suspect the coefficients in the patent represent something other than what the software is expecting, but I don't know what I don't know, so I'm not sure how to go about finding the correct interpretation of the patent numbers. See the image below with the aspherical surface on the bottom.

[image]

How can I interpret this patent data to fit into the standard definition of an aspherical surface?

Example of current faulty behavior is below. Note that I'm scaling everything by 25.0 because the patent provides an F=1 definition, but I already know the intended focal length, which changes the C1 coefficient in the patent (as the radius changes).
[image]

Comment: which patent is it?

Comment: The full patent can be found here: https://worldwide.espacenet.com/patent/search/family/005963684/publication/US4136931A?q=US4136931A